# FluentAssertions : Should().BeEquivalentTo fails for un-ordered arrays of enums

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a test in C# in which I use FluentAssertions to check the result.

```
[Fact]
public void GetEnabledFeaturesOK()
{
  LTAddOnsType[] res = new LTAddOnsType[2];
  res [0] = LTAddOnsType.Pro;
  res [1] = LTAddOnsType.Live;
  res.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] {LTAddOnsType.Live, LTAddOnsType.Pro});
}
```

with an enum like this:

```
  public enum LTAddOnsType : byte
  {
    Basic = 0,
    Pro = 1,
    Enterprise = 2,
    Live = 4
  }
```

I read that `Should().BeEquivalentTo()` by default should compare without strict ordering of the array, but clearly this is not the case, because the test fails, at least for arrays of enums.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte array answer is correct, but rather than changing the underlying enum type, you can simply override FluentAssertions' behaviour here with the following:

```cs
[Fact]
public void GetEnabledFeaturesOK()
{
  LTAddOnsType[] res = new LTAddOnsType[2];
  res [0] = LTAddOnsType.Pro;
  res [1] = LTAddOnsType.Live;
  res.Should().BeEquivalentTo(
    new[] {LTAddOnsType.Live, LTAddOnsType.Pro},
    opts => opts.WithoutStrictOrderingFor(_ => true) // Override all ordering expectations
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I tried to use opts => opts.WithoutStrictOrdering() but it didn't work, instead with your approach opts => opts.WithoutStrictOrderingFor(_ => true) it works perfectly. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately after `.WithoutStrictOrdering()` clears the ordering rules it then immediately adds a rule which enforces strict ordering for byte arrays. I disagree with this behaviour because it makes a liar out of the function, but you can read about the reasoning for it in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/974#issuecomment-440646457).

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get from the failed test case is

> Expected res[0] to equal LTAddOnsType.Live {value: 4} by value, but found LTAddOnsType.Pro {value: 1}.
> Expected res[1] to equal LTAddOnsType.Pro {value: 1} by value, but found LTAddOnsType.Live {value: 4}.
>
> With configuration:
>
> - Use declared types and members
> - Compare enums by value
> - Compare tuples by their properties
> - Compare anonymous types by their properties
> - Compare records by their members
> - Include all non-private properties
> - Include all non-private fields
> - Match member by name (or throw)
> - **Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays**
> - Without automatic conversion.

This is the default configuration. That second to last entry is the important one.

Because your enum inherits byte, you essentially have a byte array now. Changing your enum to use another data type (such as int) or removing the inheritance will resolve the problem - it will not have strict ordering. Or you can customize the configuration with [Tullo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73128534).